# Drupal 6.13 Installation - Database Error

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

I'm using Wampserver 2.0i with php 5.3.0 to install Drupal 6.13. During the installation I'm receiving the message below during the "Set up database" phase

> Operations on Unicode strings are emulated on a best-effort basis. Install the PHP mbstring extension for improved Unicode support. (Currently using Unicode library Standard PHP)
>
> Your web server does not appear to support any common database types. Check with your hosting provider to see if they offer any databases that Drupal supports.

How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal is currently borked on PHP 5.3: that may be the source of the issues you're running into as well.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this, good to know - seems they're making good progress on it though:  http://drupal.org/node/360605

Comment: That's true. I had to go back to wamp 2.0h. Now everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

It's not detecting MySql or PostGres, you either need to verify an installation of one of those, or write your own database wrapper.

[Drupal's Database Abstraction Layer](http://api.drupal.org/api/group/database)